# Solr sorting special charactes

Tags: sorting, solr, solr4

I am trying to sort the following field values using solr:

> 1, abc, 2, @h,cde

And in the result, the values are sorted like this:

> 1,2,@h,abc,cde

The desired result is:

> @h, 1,2,abc,cde (special charactes should come before everything
>   else).

Is there any way to achieve this ? The solr schema.xml file is given below:(Only the relevent field)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
    <types>
        ...............
        <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
        .............
    </types>
    <fields>
    .................
        <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="name" stored="true" type="TextField"  />
    ................    
    </fields>
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
    </schema>
```

Comment: Can you try by keeping the field name as type of String...

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Tried, didn't work

Comment: Two ideas: One, implement a [custom ICU rule](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Language+Analysis#LanguageAnalysis-UnicodeCollation) and use a ICU collation field to sort, or two, add a pattern replacer that replaces any of your special characters with a prefix that sorts in front of numeric values.

Comment: try to add "sort=<your filed name> asc" in your query url.